# Repair/delete list item with corrupted permissions

Tags: 2010, permissions, bug

I've been a SE read-only user for several years, but today I'm facing a problem I can't resolve nor find any help so I created my account. (... well actually I created it to answer to a since on-hold Star Wars question, but that's off-topic...)

So !

I have a SPListItem which had its permissions programmatically updated. For an unknown reason, this update failed (really badly) and its permissions are now corrupted. Here are the symptoms (with sitecoll + farm admin account) :

- Checking permissions via GUI throws the error : Cannot complete this action. Please try again.
- Checking permissions (RoleAssignments) via PowerShell returns null.
- $item.ResetRoleInheritance() throws "Cannot complete this action..."
- Editing/Deleting the item via GUI throws an access denied.
- Editing/Deleting the item via PowerShell throws a 0x80070005, which is also an access denied.

Actually, my problem is exactly as described in [this article](http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2010-item-level-permissions/). Unfortunately, the author's solution is to run a stored procedure, which AFAIK, is forbidden by Microsoft as any direct SQL operation in SharePoint.

Does anyone know a way to run this store procedure "legally" (= through GUI or object model) or any other way to repair or delete this item ?

Thank you for your help.

PS : BTW, if you know what could have been the cause of this failure, I'm interested too thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further search, we found out that **[some stored procedures might be used with Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841057)**.

> Examples of unsupported database changes include, but are not limited to, the following: 
>   [...]
>   Calling existing stored procedures directly, except as described in the [SharePoint Protocols documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339475.aspx)

And the *[proc_SecResetItemPerm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh626037%28v=office.12%29.aspx)* is documented in this protocol.

So we eventually used it and it worked like a charm.

For the record :
Solution found at http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2010-item-level-permissions/

1. Perform a full backup of the involved Content DB.
2. With PowerShell, get the following informations

```
$web.Site.ID   # for SiteId
$web.ID        # for WebId
$item.Url      # for Url (Warning: you'll get site-relative url, but you'll need webapp-relative url after)
$item.UniqueId # for DocId
```

3. Get the OldScopeId by querying the involved Content DB

```sql
USE [ContentDB_Name]
GO

SELECT TOP 1 [ScopeId]
FROM [ContentDB_Name].[dbo].[Perms]
WHERE ScopeUrl = 'path/site/Lists/mylist/1234_.000'
GO
```

4. Reset your item permissions by using the stored procedure

```sql
USE [ContentDB_Name]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
@NewScopeId uniqueidentifier,
@RequestGuid uniqueidentifier

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[proc_SecResetItemPerm]
@SiteId = 'ba1c5347-4bb8-443e-a8db-ce60020915d9',
@WebId = '34c030a2-0963-48cc-bf97-d9548d6b5a34',
@OldScopeId = '01bd0749-8ecc-4508-8b47-41b11f039091',
@Url = N'path/site/Lists/mylist/1234_.000',
@DocId = '961b68fa-dbd5-41b4-a098-b53a33b9e550',
@NewScopeId = @NewScopeId OUTPUT,
@RequestGuid = @RequestGuid OUTPUT

SELECT @NewScopeId as N'@NewScopeId',
@RequestGuid as N'@RequestGuid'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

5. If the Return Value equals 0, everything went well. Your item should be repaired and inherit its permissions from its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `Repair` method available on `SPContentDatabase` objects, documented by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase.repair.aspx).

You can invoke this from Powershell (once the SharePoint Powershell snapin is loaded) like so:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$databases = Get-SPContentDatabase
$databases | %{ $_.Repair($false) }
```

If you're curious about the results of the `Repair` calls, you can store the output string in a variable and optionally convert it to an XML object or save it to a file like so.

```
$databases = Get-SPContentDatabase
[xml]$xml = "<results></results>"
$databases | %{ 
    $result = $xml.createElement("result")
    $result.innerXml = $_.Repair($false) 
    $xml.SelectSingleNode("results").appendChild($result)
}
$xml.OuterXml > "Results.xml"
```

Note that passing `$true` to `Repair` will give it permission to simply delete the corrupted objects instead of trying to fix them. In some cases, that may be the best fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thriggle. Unfortunatelly I can't try it since my problem is resolved. But I'm curious, do you know if Repair($true) is OK with Microsoft ? It's object model accessing, so I'd say it is, but there's something close in the forbidden operations list : "Running DBCC_CHECKDB WITH REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS (However, running DBCC_CHECKDB WITH REPAIR_FAST and REPAIR_REBUILD is supported, as these commands only update the indexes of the associated database.)" [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841057)

Comment: Yep, I'm certain it's supported. The forbidden operation is referring specifically to a SQL command, [`DBCC CHECKDB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx). The `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` option on that command is unsupported because threatens referential integrity. `SPContentDatabase.Repair(true)` will delete orphaned objects, but won't jeopardize the database's referential integrity.